# I need to search a fix length number from string having same data with extra digit and word using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to search a 5 digit number (Like 25467) from string having data with extra number and string like ((925467,klm25467,-725467,y25467) in different rows of column. I want only 25467 result in each row.

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a regex function:

```
with test1 as 
(
select '925467' digit  from dual union all
select 'klm25467' digit  from dual union all
select '-725467' digit  from dual union all
select '-725467ff' digit  from dual union all
select '-725467s' digit  from dual union all
select 'y25467' digit  from dual 
)
select regexp_substr(digit,'[2]{1}[0-9]{3}[7]{1}') from test1
```

Result will show every number in string that starts with number 2 and ends with number 7 and has 5 digits.

Result:

```
25467
25467
25467
25467
25467
25467
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your numbers appear at the end of the string, get the last 5 characters of the string:

```sql
SELECT value,
       SUBSTR(value, -5) AS number_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) as 
  select '925467'   from dual union all
  select 'klm25467' from dual union all
  select '-725467'  from dual union all
  select 'y25467'   from dual;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | NUMBER_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 925467 | 25467 |
> | klm25467 | 25467 |
> | -725467 | 25467 |
> | y25467 | 25467 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=79a88eb310fd2ec32eb7b896d476ab1b)*